# How to show complete Excel data with Excel Headers in DataGridView? Cells becomes empty when I put headers on OleDB Connection

Tags: c#, excel-2016

I want to view the Excel data with headers inside datagridview.

I have tried changing HDR=Yes to HDR=No. It shows all the data but I have headers on the Excel file.

I changed this code:

`string pathconn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1\";";`

To:

`string pathconn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1\";";`

[This is my Excel data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCFkE.png)

Comment: I had same problem. in my case, the problem was the string inside the header of the column. if the header containt '.' (dot) then the whole column was not shown.
I suppose the problem was in the type of characters. try to remove any non-ASCII chars from your header and try again.

Comment: Still no changes. I tried to replace columns with '.'(dot), also i have columns without dot but still the data is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put in the column name the text of the first row of the datatable.
Then delete the row.

```
Datatable dtExcel = importaExcelaDT(filePath);

for(int i = 0; i < dtExcel.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    string columnName = dtExcel.Rows[0][i].ToString();
    if (columnName == "") //throws error if column name is empty
        columnName = " ";
    dtExcel.Columns[i].ColumnName = columnName;
}
dtExcel.Rows.RemoveAt(0);

yourDataGridView.DataSource = dtExcel;
```

Answer (score 0):

I get data with headers with this function.

```
public DataTable importaExcelaDT(string file)
        {

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();

OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();

string cadenaConexion = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + file + "';Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No;IMEX=1\";";

OleDbConnection olConexion = new OleDbConnection(cadenaConexion);

olConexion.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
dt = olConexion.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
string sheet = dt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

cmdExcel.Connection = olConexion;
cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheet + "]"; 

oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
oda.Fill(dtExcel);
olConexion.Close();

olConexion.Dispose();
oda.Dispose();
return dtExcel;
}
```

Comment: Still didn't answer my question :( But thanks for the effort :)

Comment: This function returns a datatable with all data, including headers. You just have to assign the datatable as datagridview data source.
For some reason, HDR must be No.
If you run it with HDR=Yes it does not return the headers.

Comment: https://imgur.com/pevYZEu 
This is the output of your code that i have tried but inside the red box should be the headers of my data.

Comment: Yes, it returns all the data that i want but the Headers are named in F1, F2, F3 ...

Comment: Now I understand what you want.
You want to create the grid headers as the Excel headers.

Comment: Yup, that's the output I want.